# Connecting one local script with the other

Tags: javascript

The question is how to connect two local scripts (with no interner-connection at all). The whole task is controlling one opened local page from other opened page (same or different browser). That couldn't be bridged through web-server.
I have no idea who to make this except writing to localStorage on one page and constantly checking from another (or using a handler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar requirement, and localStorage is the only reasonable option I found. You *could* persist some info on the server, but if you need real-time update or frequent communication between pages, the server side methods begin to slow down the application.

> I have no idea who to make this except writing to localStorage on one page and constantly checking from another (or using a handler)

With [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), you don't have to constantly check the state of storage. It does provide a storage event that you could bind to:

```
window.onstorage = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

This event would be triggered when you modify the storage through another tab. Something like,

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value');
```

So `localStorage` can, in principle, serve as a basic communication channel between two tabs - running on the same domain.

Some libraries are also available that provide advanced features based on localStorage. I have used [Crosstab](https://github.com/tejacques/crosstab), in past, and it works pretty fine for most purposes.